# How to convert list of ascii value say [192] to binary <<192>> in erlang

Tags: erlang

Example

6> erlang:list_to_binary([192]).

<<"À">>

I want output as 
<<192>>

Can anyone help

Comment: They're actually the same `<<192>> == <<"À">>. %=> true`, unless you mean you just want to change how they're printed in the REPL.

Comment: use shell:strings(false).

Comment: This is mentioned in [the "Lists" documentation section](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/erlang/1128/data-types/3711/lists#t=201610061438337311596) (near the bottom).

Answer (score 2):

This happens because Erlang represents strings as lists of integers, so if you ask the shell to print a list of integers, the shell takes a guess as to whether you want to see it as a list of numbers or as a string. The shell bases its guess on checking whether or not the list contains all printable characters, so you can force a string to be unprintable. In Erlang/OTP R16B and above, you can use the function [shell:strings/1](http://erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html#strings-1) to turn off this behaviour in the shell:

```
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

local recon loaded
Eshell V8.1  (abort with ^G)
1> erlang:list_to_binary([192]).
<<"À">>
2> shell:strings(false).
true
3> erlang:list_to_binary([192]).
<<192>>
4>
```

NB:This is option global for all node shells, thus for longer living nodes it best to set it back to the original value after you are done.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a list such as [1,2,3,4] to <<1,2,3,4>>:

```
lists:foldl(fun(N, Acc) -> << Acc/binary, N >> end, <<>>, [1,2,3,4]).
```

Comment: There's no need to do this -- this is exactly the same as `list_to_binary/1`: `lists:foldl(fun(N, Acc) -> << Acc/binary, N >> end, <<>>, [192]). %=> <<"À">>`.